# Incompatibility of the motherboard and HDD

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I have a problem with my old HDD that refuses to work with the new motherboard; the disk just doesn't show up in BIOS. Same results with different SATA ports and cables, but this disk does work on the old PC. BIOS and Windows just don't show this disk, and Ubuntu shows a number of "sata: COMRESET failed" errors for this disk.
Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like the drive is not operational; It’s not possible for a SATA drive to be incompatible with a motherboard with a SATA port

Comment: @Ramhound it is operational. I've just checked it with the new PC via a USB adapter and it works. Not via SATA cable, though.

Comment: I wonder if the new BIOS (new CPU) recognizes the old drive. Get the data from it and copy that to the new computer.

Comment: Does your new motherboard recognize a different (new) HDD with the SATA ports and cables you tried?

Comment: @dirkt yes. Not really new, but it does recognize another old HDD on the same port/cable.

Comment: Guess: The SATA timing for older SATA protocol variants is slightly off on your new motherboard and the timing is slightly off on your first old HDD as well. Your old motherboard has wide enough tolerances to compensate, and the combination new motherboard/old HDD cannot compensate. Have you tried an USB-to-SATA adapter? You can even use them internally, if you want.

Comment: @dirkt never heard about such possibility, but it sounds feasible. I wonder if there is any way to tweak SATA timing parameters?

Comment: It's likely some accident of passive elements and/or your SATA controller chip just being at the edge of tolerances. You could desolder your SATA controller chip, and replace it with a new one ... if you have the equipment for that. But, all of this is guesswork. The only way to find out is to capture the SATA protocol on the wire and look at what goes wrong. Which again needs special equipment. If you edit your question with the exact error message, maybe they contain some hints. Or not.

Comment: Does the disk show in disk management when connected? you may have to use the "import foreign disk" while in disk management.